How to return the list and count of unique combinations based on a primary column?
I have the below table structure and want to return a count of the unique combination of relationships based on product. Relationships has 14 unique values



customer ID
relationship
product ID




123
Primary
abc


456
Secondary
abc


789
Other
abc


987
Primary
xyz



The final output I'm trying to achieve would be something like



Relationship Type
Relationship Count
Product Count




Primary, Secondary, Other
1
1


Primary
1
1




SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
SET ANSI_NULLS ON;

WITH RelationshipCounts AS (
    SELECT 
        product_id,
        STUFF((
            SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + relationship
            FROM Relationships AS inner_table
            WHERE inner_table.product_id = outer_table.product_id
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') AS relationship_type,
        COUNT(DISTINCT relationship) AS relationship_count
    FROM Relationships AS outer_table
    GROUP BY product_id
),
FinalOutput AS (
    SELECT 
        relationship_type,
        SUM(relationship_count) AS relationship_count,
        COUNT(DISTINCT product_id) AS product_count
    FROM RelationshipCounts
    GROUP BY relationship_type
)

SELECT 
    relationship_type, 
    relationship_count, 
    product_count
FROM FinalOutput
ORDER BY relationship_type;


